# How to prevent the laptop monitor from going blank when locking the screen

Tags: gnome, 16.10, lock-screen, ubuntu-gnome

I have tried all I could think of (and find online), but I was unable to make my Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 **NOT** turn off the laptop monitor (and any attached external monitors) when I lock the screen via Super+L.

The only temporary solution that I found was to move the mouse just after the lock happens, but the screen still goes blank after a while and I can't find the exact gnome conf setting to prolong that delay.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same question but with Gnome on Fedora!